# What other celestial bodies are in Barrayar's solar system?

Tags: vorkosigan-saga

In Lois McMaster Bujold's *Barrayar* series, I can't recall any mention of Barrayar having a moon or of there being any other planets in its solar system.  Are there any references to them in the books?

Comment: @Gallifreyan: why'd you remove the Lois McMaster Bujold tag?

Comment: @Martha Our [current consensus](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7924/70236) about author tags suggests we use them only when asking about the author's life, or about overarching themes in an author's work that are not confined to a single work or a franchise.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Barrayar had two *unnamed* satellites, according to [this source](http://www.dendarii.com/bujold_faq.html#barr-moon).

> Two. Smaller than Earth's moon. Names and colors not specified. (25 Dec 1998)

Comment: Here is the source: http://www.dendarii.com/bujold_faq.html#barr-moon